# MySQL query: display articles and their comments where users `deletion` field is not `1` and `active` is `NULL`

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to just display articles and their comments where users `deletion` field is not `1` and `active` is `NULL`, but for some reason my query displays comments from articles where the `deletion` field is `1`.  How do I fix this?

MySQL tables

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    username VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    password CHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    active CHAR(32),
    deletion TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id),
    UNIQUE KEY (username)
);

CREATE TABLE articles_comments (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    parent_comment_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    article_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    comment TEXT NOT NULL,
    date_created DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    KEY user_id (user_id),
    KEY article_id (article_id)
);

CREATE TABLE users_articles (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    title TEXT NOT NULL,
    summary TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
    content LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

articles_comments tables input

```
comment_id  parent_comment_id   user_id     article_id  comment
1           0                   1           1           -
2           0                   2           1           -
3           0                   2           2           -
4           0                   1           2           -
5           0                   2           3           -
6           0                   2           4           -
7           1                   2           1           -
8           2                   2           1           -
9           0                   3           1           -
```

users_articles tables input

```
id  user_id     title   summary     content
1   3           -       -           -
2   4           -       -           -
3   4           -       -           -
4   4           -       -           -
```

users tables input

```
user_id     username    password    deletion    active
1           -           -           0           NULL
2           -           -           0           NULL
3           -           -           1           NULL
4           -           -           0           NULL
```

My Current Display Output

```
user_id     comment_id      article_id 
1           1               1
2           2               1
2           3               2
1           4               2
2           5               3
2           6               4
2           7               1
2           8               1
```

My Desired Output

```
user_id     comment_id      article_id 
2           3               2
1           4               2
2           5               3
2           6               4
```

My current MySQL code.

```
SELECT *
  FROM users_articles
    INNER JOIN articles_comments ON users_articles.id = articles_comments.article_id
    INNER JOIN users ON articles_comments.user_id = users.user_id
  WHERE users.active IS NULL
    AND users.deletion = 0
```

Comment: The current display output matches the description of your desired results. The only user with a `deletion` of 1 is user 3, who isn't listed in the results. Do you want articles and their comments where no comment on each article is from a deleted user, even though other comments (and the article itself) were not from deleted users? E.g. were user 1 deleted, then any comment for article 2 would no longer be included in the output.

Answer (score 0):

try this

**EDIT :**

```
   SELECT * FROM users_articles,articles_comments,users where users_articles.id = articles_comments.article_id and articles_comments.user_id = users.user_id and users_articles.user_id=users.user_id and userusers.active IS NULL AND users.deletion = 0;
```

Note : its not advisable to select all (*) with joined tables.

Comment: It still leaves out some of my comments that should not be left out :(